# Jenkins Checkstyle trend graph not showing historical failures

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, checkstyle

I'm using the checkstyle plugin to show the results of Node.js ESLint analysis. This is my build step in a `post` section of a declarative Jenkins pipeline

```
 step([$class: 'CheckStylePublisher',
       pattern: 'standard.xml',
       unHealthy: '0',
       usePreviousBuildAsReference: true,
       canRunOnFailed: true])
```

The build will fail when the linter fails and this is shown correctly in the trend graph. But then once the build passes, the failing builds are not shown in the trend graph anymore.

In the pictures, builds 75 and 76 failed due to linting errors. These errors were shown correctly in the trend graph when they happened. But then once the errors were fixed the failures disappear from the trend graph - 75 and 76 aren't shown at all. I'd like it to show all the builds even if they fail.

[image: build results]
[image]